# How to extract audio and save it to a file in yt-dlp?

Tags: python, yt-dlp

i am new to this particular library and cannot find how to extract audio and save it to a file in yt-dlp.

My code right now is:
`system("youtube-dl -x -q -o \'" + PATH_TO_SAVE + song + ".%(ext)s\' \'" + link + "\'")`

Whenever i run this, I receive an error -
 `youtube-dl: error: Cannot download a video and extract audio into the same file! Use "'C:\Users\Jeet\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\SpeechRecognition\Hitler.%(ext)s" instead of "'C:\Users\Jeet\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\SpeechRecognition\Hitler" as the output template Downloaded Godzilla`

Please help me with this

Comment: You title mentions yt-dlp while your code calls youtube-dl. Anyway, it seems that you should replace `%` with `%%` on windows. See this [github issue](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/2550)

Comment: Ya thats my bad, but that does not solve the issue though, the error message reads the same

Comment: Something's not right with your (single) quotes: they're not balanced. Maybe you should use double ones? Are there whitespaces in `song`? The error mentions `'C:\Users\Jeet\Desktop\Projects\PythonProjects\SpeechRecognition\Hitler`